# Redirect only non-existing sub-directories to another domain using wildcard

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

In Apache, how do i redirect all non-existing directories for one domain (E.g. http://example.com/*.*) to another (e.g. http://example2.com/*.*)? I don't want the redirect to occur if the directory exists on the first server (http://example.com/). Just for non-existing directories.

Example:

- http://example.com/directoryA   <--- Exists on the server, so it should NOT redirect.
- http://example.com/directoryB   <--- Does NOT exist, so it should redirect to http://example2.com/directoryB

Is this even possible? The trouble is that i need the redirect to be a wildcard rather than having to define all the possible redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in your .htaccess file on `example.com`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ http://example2.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Change to `R=301` when you confirm it's working.

Comment: That's a start, but it's doing two weird things. 1) It's redirecting everything, including directories that exist. 2) For the redirect to work, i have to specify a file. So http://examplea.com/directoryA doesn't work unless i do http://examplea.com/directoryA/index.html. Then it works.

Comment: Try the slightly modified version.